# Bochner integral in sequence spaces

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, bochner-spaces

Let $X$ be a (real) sequence Banach space, such as $c_{0},\ell_{p}$, etc. and $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow X$ continuous. Then, it seems "quite intuitive" that if $f(t):=(f_{1}(t),f_{2}(t),\ldots,f_{n}(t),\ldots)\in X$ for every $t\in I$, and certain continuous functions $f_{i}$ we have

$$
\int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds=\big(\int_{0}^{t}f_{1}(s)ds,\int_{0}^{t}f_{2}(s)ds,\ldots, \int_{0}^{t}f_{n}(s)ds,\ldots \big)\quad \textrm{for all }t\in I,
$$

where the left-hand side integral means in the Bochner sense and the integrals in the right-hand side mean in the Lebesgue sense.

But, is true the above equality?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: Isn't the thing on the right a Pettis integral of $f$?

Answer (score 0):

Fix $n$. Define the functional $g\in X^*$ by $g(f) = f_n$. Then
$$
\left\langle g, \int_0^1f(s)ds \right\rangle 
=\int_0^1 \langle g,f(s)\rangle ds
=\int_0^1 f_n(s)ds.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I do not understand at all the answer. With your proof, Can we derive that the assert of the post is true? Again, thanks.